# Issues with ghost installation and npm

Tags: node.js, ghost

I got this error when trying to install the ghost blogging software.

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /Users/abe/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/abe/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Comment: Can you post the command you ran before you received the error?

Comment: npm install --production
 npm start